# Programmatically adding entitydatasource bound dropdownlist to panel and submit values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add named dropdownlists to a panel (or a placeholder if better) in my aspx form.

Here is what I have :

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="elementDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ThermoDBEntities" DefaultContainerName="ThermoDBEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="elements" EntityTypeFilter="element"></asp:EntityDataSource>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1">

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ElementDDL" runat="server" DataSourceID="elementDS" DataTextField="designation" DataValueField="Id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("element_Id") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

</asp:Panel>

<asp:Button ID="Buttonplus" runat="server" Text="+" OnClick="Buttonplus_Click" class="btn btn-success" />
```

and in the code behind :

```
public partial class lotdepoudre_creation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int temp=0;
    int i = 2;

    protected void Buttonplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList Dropdownlistnew = new DropDownList();
        StringBuilder stringnomddl = new StringBuilder();
        stringnomddl.Append("ddl" + i.ToString());
        Panel1.Controls.Add(Dropdownlistnew);
        Dropdownlistnew.ID = stringnomddl.ToString();
        i++;

    }
}
```

I get an error on the ElementDDL dropdownlist that says :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control

How can I put a ddl with an entitydatasource to the panel? How can I  programmatically add some data? How to define a datasource with entityframework for them?

In addition, after adding the dropdownlist, I have a submit button for inserting the selected values in a database. Can this work with the added ddlists ?